Gauging users excitement via Avatars in a small space
I'm working on an app that let's users show how excited they are for given proposed activities.
It is quite a challenge because a lot is going on in a confined space.

The view should work reasonably well for up to 6 people.
Your own excitment should be editable (this can also be done by an overlay).
The excitement doesn't need to be exact. You don't type in a number, you just roughly move a slider so to say.
It should rather be playful than end up looking like a grid.
Avatars can additionally express that someone "discarded" an activity (removed it from their list) or they left a comment

Overall I like the idea of having some sort of scale rather than just having something like "thumbs up" or "two thumbs up" icons, because it makes it more comparable. Also I would like users to express that they're really hyped for something.
Here are my mockups so far:


I think having numbers for excitement levels will give you more options:

you can easily compare them
you can order them
you can filter them
you can average them per activity

Those numbers can also be represented as thumbs-ups, hearts, stars etc.

That part aside, it seems that you want to build a dashboard showing people's attitude towards different activities.
A few things to consider:

You said up to 6 people, but you might need more later on, so the UI should also have a "more" or "+" button for each activity.

Since there will be many avatars on the screen, the excitement meter should be obvious enough to be understood at a glance. A subtle dot might not be enough.

When putting avatars on top of vertical bars, they look like a podium. Bars are definitely more obvious than the small dots. You could try placing the avatars inside bars, with some gradient for bars.

Even if you want it to be playful, when you have a dashboard, readability requires some sort of order, and it's usually looking like a grid.

Never rotate avatars. This is a general rule in UI.

When using very small icons (like the ones for replied and discarded), they need to be very simple. An X for discard would be easier to read. You could also try emoji, since they are usually understood.

You will need to add hidden descriptions for each avatar and excitement level to be read by screen readers.


